# api.instagram CORB network error because of jsonp response header with `Content-Type: application/json`

Tags: instagram-api, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm using [fetch-jsonp](https://github.com/camsong/fetch-jsonp) to fetch `https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=<embedUrl>` to use the `response.html` to embed on my website.

But I'm having a problem on my requests getting a [CORB](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768) error.

This is my snippet code:

```
fetchJsonp("https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=" + url, {
  timeout: 800,
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
```

My console:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=<embedUrl> with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I handle embedding from twitter with the same snipped code accessing `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=<embedUrl>` and it works fine.

Since twitter response have a `Content-Type: application/javascript` it works, but instagram response have a `Content-Type: application/json` and it doesn't.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had the same problem, but switching from jsonp to json did the trick. For example:

```
fetch("https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=" + url)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(json){
    console.log(json)
  })
```

Comment: Indeed, switching to JSON rather than JSONP works. This should be marked as the accepted answer for any other lost souls coming here with the same issue.